# Should the compiler have caught this mistake with a generic collection?

Tags: java, generics

The following code throws an `ArrayStoreException` at `toArray()`.  Should not the compiler have caught the blunder and reported an type conflict given that `toArray` takes a `V[]` and the registry Map is typed with a value of `Map<String,String>`?

```
private Map<String,Map<String,String>>  registry;

...

registry=new TreeMap<String,Map<String,String>>(String.CASE_INSENSITIVE_ORDER));

...

void removeTargets(String[] clsarr, String hdl) {
        if(clsarr==null) { clsarr=registry.values().toArray(new String[0]); }
    ...
    }
```

It looks like a compiler bug to me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not a compiler bug.  Arguably a library bug though.

The type of `Collection.toArray()` is `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`.  Note that `T` is a type parameter to the `toArray` method and has no relationship to `Collection`'s type parameter.

This bug would have been caught if the signature of `Collection.toArray` were `<T super E> T[] toArray(T[] a)` but that would make it tough to use since it's not legal to do `new Map<String, String>[0]` -- you get a "generic array creation" error.

Comment: And once again generics support is "better than nothing, but leaves a lot to be desired".  Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: @Software Monkey.  Yeah.  Type systems in widely used programming languages have holes in them that errors can slip through.  This one is not due to any theoretical limitation, but due to the early design of the Java array type that decided to gloss over variance issues by saying a `String[]` is an `Object[]` which made it hard to work array types into the generic type system that tries to handle variance properly.

Answer (score 2):

No. The [`toArray`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html#toArray(T%5B%5D)) function is:

> `<T> T[] toArray(T[] a)`
>
> Returns an array containing all of the elements in this collection; the runtime type of the returned array is that of the specified array.

where the type in the generic collection is `E`. So you can pass in a variable of any type there.

It's a klunky design cause the generic types are erased upon compile time, so there's no way to return an array of the proper type at run-time. That's why you have to provide the type in the `toArray` call. IMO it's pretty inelegant - passing in an array of the type you want - but Java didn't introduce any way to provide a type annotation here.